# Not able to write to pendrive

Tags: boot, mount, live-usb, read-only

I have a 2 GB pendrive(FAT16)... I used dd command to make it bootable

> dd if=archlinux.iso of=/mnt/pd/

But now when I tried to rename some folders in it... it gives an error saying this is read-only fs

I even tried remounting

> mymac@juggernaut:~/Desktop/tejas$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1

This is the error

> mount: cannot remount block device /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the `dd` command to write to the drive while it is unmounted, and should not be writing to its mounted location (/mnt/pd in your example) if you want to make a bootable USB.

So assuming that your pendrive shows on your system as `/dev/sdb` the command would be:

```
dd if=archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Be sure to use `/dev/sdb` not `/dev/sdb1`, or it will not be bootable.

It would also be worth checking whether there is some sort of physical write protection on the drive, like a read-only switch on the side.

**As always be very careful with the dd command, it hasn't earned the nickname 'disk destroyer' for no reason!**